# Contextual ActionBar not covering Toolbar

Tags: android

I am creating a contextual action bar over a toolbar .My toolbar minimum height is set to 100dp.
First if i set

```
 actionmode =      MyActivity.this.startActionMode(new mycallback());
```

and the height of toolbar is wrap_content the toolbar is covered with contextual action bar .But if height is 100 dp the contextual bar only covers part of toolbar.
how can set the height of contextual actionbar.
if i try to set

```
actionmode.setCustomView(v);
```

and the View v is simly a Linearlayout with height of 100dp there is error.

If i use

```
actionmode =      toolbar.startActionMode(new mycallback());
```

as suggested in some stackoverflow thread, then i get a CAB which is placed above the toolbar and not over it.
Kindly update how can i change the size of CAB to completely overlay the Toolbar.
Also the ShareActionProvider on the CAB does not show any applications for the following action even though if used without CAB the ShareActionProvider shows a no of applications. Why is this behaviour of ShareActionProvider for CAB. Am i missing something to set.

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

          //  invalidateOptionsMenu();
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myprovider, menu);

            MenuItem mi=menu.findItem(R.id.pprovider);
             sp=new ShareActionProvider(Material_Example.this);
            MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(mi,sp);
            if(sp!=null) {
                Toast.makeText(Material_Example.this,"it is not null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                sp.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
                sp.setShareIntent(getmyintent());
            }
return true;
}

    private Intent getmyintent() {

        Intent ii=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        ii.setType("image/*");
        return ii;
    }
```

[image]
[image]
thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get the CAB to overlay the toolbar?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

add

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

to your theme